# Equivalent of abline in plotly

Tags: r, plot, plotly

I would like to add a line (not just vertical or horizontal) to a `plotly` chart

```
library(plotly)
d = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
plot_ly(d, x = ~x, y = ~y, type='scatter')
```

Say I want `(D) y = 2x` as a line is there a way for me to plot without generating the data myself in another column of `d`

Comment: Are you looking for something like `plot_ly(d, x = ~x, y = ~y, type='scatter', mode = "markers") %>% add_trace(x = ~2*x, y = ~y, mode = "lines")`

Comment: yes, but what if I have several graphs and I do not know the `xlim` of the 'widest' sub-plot, I might end up with a line that does not 'cover' the whole graph

Comment: Add on one of these?  `%>%  layout(xaxis = list(range = c(~min(x), ~max(x))))`?  I might need another example if this isn't getting at the problem.

Comment: Did not know that, I'll check asap

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093169/horizontal-vertical-line-in-plotly) a related post can be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There at least two ways of simulating `abline`.

- Add another trace with the start and end point
- Add a `line` shape to the `layout` with the start and end point

The disadvantage is that the `min` and `max` for each trace needs to be calculated (`Plotly` needs to do that anyway but it bloats the code).

The alternative would be draw the line from one extreme to the other other and then set the `xaxis` and `yaxis` `range` manually.

In the example below the red line is the added trace, while the black line is added via `shape` `line`.

[image]

```
library('plotly')

#a function to calculate your abline
p_abline <- function(x, a=2, b=-5){
  y <- a * x + b
  return(y)
}

#create an empty plot    
p <- plot_ly()

#list with all your x and y values
x <-  list(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,6), (1:5))
y <-  list(c(1,2,3), c(0,5,10), sample(-10:10, 5))

#loop through the x/y values and determine min/max
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  p<-add_trace(p, y=y[[i]], x=x[[i]] , type="scatter", mode="markers+lines")
  if (i == 1 || max(x[[i]]) > max_x) {
    max_x = max(x[[i]])
  }
  if (i == 1 || max(y[[i]]) > max_y) {
    max_y = max(y[[i]])
  }
  if (i == 1 || min(x[[i]]) < min_x) {
    min_x = min(x[[i]])
  }
  if (i == 1 || min(y[[i]]) < min_y) {
    min_y = min(y[[i]])
  }

}

#add a trace to simulate abline
p<-add_trace(p, x=c(min_x, max_x), y=c(p_abline(min_x), p_abline(max_x)) , type="scatter", mode="lines", name='abline')

#add a shape (line) to simulate abline
p <- p %>% layout(
  shapes=list(type='line', x0=min_x, x1=max_x, y0=p_abline(min_x, -1, 3), y1=p_abline(max_x, -1, 3))
  )

p
```

Comment: very verbose solution. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plotly)
d = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
plot_ly(d, x = ~x, y = ~y, type='scatter') %>%
  add_trace(d, x = ~x, y = ~x * 2, type = "scatter")
```

It turns out you can do math right within the add_trace function call where you're saying what y should be. So you can tell plotly to just multiply that column by two right in the argument.