# Plotly in R - Diagonal AB line

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly, abline

I require a diagonal line through the origin of this plot

Something similar to ggplot2's `geom_abline(intercept = 0 , slope = 1)`
But for plotly in R

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
fig
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seemed like the best example I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980772/equivalent-of-abline-in-plotly 

Perhaps it's a bit easier using ggplotly, but I cannot vouch for that.

Comment: If you're looking for a trend line in plotly (which is the role abline fills, this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593153/plotly-regression-line-r) might help.

Comment: Possibly cheating, but : `library(plotly); library(ggplot);

fig <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline();
ggplotly(fig)`

Comment: You may try `add_segments`. Try `p <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length, type = "scatter") %>%
  add_segments(x=4, y=4, xend = 8, yend = 8)
p
`

Comment: @Brad old question - nevertheless, I left an approach below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A line shape could be used to achive this:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Petal.Length)
fig %>%
  layout(shapes = list(list(
    type = "line", 
    x0 = 0, 
    x1 = ~max(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length), 
    xref = "x",
    y0 = 0, 
    y1 = ~max(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length),
    yref = "y",
    line = list(color = "black")
  )))
```

[image: result]

Also see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34097929/9841389).

Btw. via `xref = "paper"` we don't need to specify start and end points for the line, however the line is no longer aligned with the axes.

Comment: Can you also show the shape in the legend?

Comment: @H.berg this is possible since [plotly.js v2.25.0](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2250----2023-07-25). However, the R library  {plotly} [currently uses](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-to-plotlyjs) plotly.js v2.11.1. Accordingly, you'll have to wait for an update.

Comment: Is there a way to manual add it to the legend?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly let me know if this is what you were anticipating.

```
fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = iris)

iris %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~Sepal.Length) %>% 
  add_markers(y = ~Petal.Length) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~Sepal.Length, y = fitted(fit))
```

Comment: This is a linear model. I want a line x = y which is uninfluenced by any data points.