# Combine a ggplot2 graph with a plot_ly one in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to combine a graph generated with ggplot2 and converted to plot_ly,

```r
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.1, 1e7), breaks = 10^(0:7), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.1, 1e7), breaks = 10^(0:7), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept =l1, slope = 1), color = "blue") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -l1, slope = 1), color = "blue") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept =l2, slope = 1), color = "red") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -l2, slope = 1), color = "red") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept =l3, slope = 1), color = "green") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = -l3, slope = 1), color = "green")

plot <- ggplotly(plot)
```

[image: plot1-ggplot2]

with another one generated with `plot_ly`.

```r
p2 <- plot_ly(data = df, x = ~sample1, y = ~sample2, type = "scatter", 
   mode = "markers", marker = list(symbol = "cross",size = 4, opacity = 0.5, 
   color = "rgba(50,50,50,0.5)",alpha = I(0.8))) %>%
   layout(xaxis = list(type = "log", range = c(-1, 7), dtick = 1, 
          ticklen = 5, showgrid=TRUE, gridwidth=1),
         yaxis = list(type = "log", range = c(-1, 7), dtick = 1, 
                      ticklen = 5))
```

[image: plot2-plotly]

Basically, I want the first plot to be the background of the second one, keeping also the axis as they are in the second plot.

Comment: Maybe try to add ablines using plotly only, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41980772/680068