# Overlay vertical line on top of histogram in R using Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have an histogram like the one below and I want to plot a vertical line of a specific value on top of the histogram.

My code for the histogram is:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50,mean = 50,sd = 10), type = "histogram")
p
```

I want to overlay a line on top of the histogram, for example say,

```
x <- 42
```

[image]

Can anyone help getting this?

Comment: `abline(v=42)` or, using your object `abline(v=x)`

Comment: I have tried that. I get an error `plot.new has not been called yet`

Comment: Oh you're using plotly, try plotting with 'histogram'?

Comment: I am restricted to use only `plotly` here

Comment: `add.trace` helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50,mean = 50,sd = 10), type = "histogram") %>%
  add_segments(x=42, y=0, xend=42, yend=14, line=list(color="red", width = 4))
p
```

A different solution (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093169/horizontal-vertical-line-in-plotly) for details):

```
vline <- function(x = 0, color = "red") {
  list(
    type = "line", 
    y0 = 0, 
    y1 = 1, 
    yref = "paper",
    x0 = x, 
    x1 = x, 
    line = list(color = color)
  )
}
p <- plot_ly(x = ~rnorm(50, mean = 50,sd = 10), type = "histogram") %>%
  layout(shapes = list(vline(42)))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Marco. This works. Do you know if there is there a way to find the max height of the histogram so that I can use that to specify `yend` instead of hard coding it?

Comment: @krish did you ever find a solution for finding the yend  ?

Comment: @MarcoSandri did you ever find a solution for finding the yend ?

Comment: thanks @MarcoSandri this works fine, was looking for this solution for 10 hours there isn't much info on this