# Plotly 3D scatterplot to read in 2D

Tags: r, plotly

When creating a scatterplot on plotly, how can I add dotted lines that go from a datapoint to the axis plane so that when downloaded as a 2D picture the reader can have a sense of the values of those datapoints?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093169/horizontal-vertical-line-in-plotly), I think is a first approach of what you are looking for

Comment: Is dotted lines a priority? For simplicity, just hover over your points, take a screenshot, then save the screenshot.