# rangeslider in ggplotly(): start and end of slider doesn't work

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly, ggplotly, rangeslider

I want to use `rangeslider()` with `ggplotly()`. Unfortunately, defining the **start** and **end** of the slider does not work with `ggplotly()`. I'm using the `rangeslider()` in the server.R of an RShiny App. In the server it looks like the following code snippet:

```
output$maForwardVsSpotPLOT <- renderPlotly({
    plotFvsS <- MAForwardVsSpotMeanDifference(input$maStrategy, input$maTradingDays, input$maDateRange[1], 
                                              input$maDateRange[2], input$maPeriod)$FvsSMeanDiffPlot
    
    ggplotly(plotFvsS, dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>%
      rangeslider() %>%     # start = input$maDateRange[1], end = input$maDateRange[2]
      layout(hovermode = "x")
  
  })
```

In the UI I have:

```
tabItem(tabName = "maForwardVsSpot", 
        fluidRow(width = 7, dateRangeInput(inputId = "maFFDateRange", label = "Date Range", 
                                           start = "2018-01-01", end = Sys.Date()),
        fluidRow(width = 7, plotlyOutput(outputId = "maForwardVsSpotPLOT", width = "900px", 
                                         height = "600px")
```

plotFvsS is defined in an external function (`MAForwardVsSpotMeanDifference`) and looks like this:

```
plotFvsS  <- ggplot(dt.allDataFvsS, aes(x = date, y = meanDifference)) +
             coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-25, 25)) +   # Note: using ylim throws all data outside of ylim away!!! using coord_cartesian solves this problem
             ggtitle("Price Difference Forward vs. Spot") +
             geom_line(color = "blue", size = 0.9) + 
             labs(y = "EUR/MWh", x = "Date") +
             theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 9), axis.title = element_text(size = 5),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                   panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black", size = 1)) + 
             theme_bw(base_size = 17) +
             theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
             geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black") +
             geom_hline(yintercept = c(20,10,-10,-20), color = "#CCCCCC") +
             geom_vline(xintercept = c(12481, 12784, 13149, 13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 15706, 
                                       16071, 16436, 16801, 17167, 17532, 17897, 18262, 18628)) +
             geom_vline(xintercept = c(12509, 12600, 12692, 12874, 12965, 13057, 13239, 13330, 13422, 13604, 
                                       13695, 13787, 13970, 14061, 14153, 14335, 14426, 14528, 14700, 14791, 
                                       14883, 15065, 15156, 15248, 15431, 15522, 15614, 15796, 15887, 15979, 
                                       16161, 16252, 16344, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16892, 16983, 17075, 17257, 
                                       17348, 17440, 17622, 17713, 17987, 18078, 18170, 18353, 18444, 18536), 
                        linetype = "dashed", color = "#666666")  +
             geom_vline(xintercept = 17805, linetype = "dashed", color = "red")
```

How can I add **start** and **end** in the `rangeslider()`?

Comment: Hi Michaela, it would be easier if you provide your ui and server code (relating to this particular plot, doesn't have to be the whole app) in order to help.

Comment: And please also provide some example data (by using `dput`)

Comment: Hi @Phil ! I have edited the missing parts (UI, more information of the server.R). The plot works and is displayed almost correctly. The only thing that bothers me is the ```rangeslider()```, I would like it to start and end exactly where I or someone else choose the parameters as input.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately this is an [open issue](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1551) with `ggplotly`. You could switch to `plot_ly()` until the bug is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the information @ismirsehregal.. Unfortunately, the whole plot is created with ```ggplot()```

Comment: @ismirsehregal I've now tried to do it with ```plot_ly()``` and unfortunately I can't insert vertical lines like in the code above with ```geom_vline()```. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093169/horizontal-vertical-line-in-plotly). Also feel free to create another question if you have issues to mimic the plot via `plot_ly`.